# How to write an editable ordered list in html which can use tab key for browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an ordered list (HTML), which you can edit the content for each list item, while you can tab between each list item using tab key.

I know the contenteditable attribute, but it do not solve my tabbing problem.

This picture give you an idea what this looks like:
[image]

This is what I currently have:

```
<div id="roster">
  <ol contenteditable="true">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
 </div>
```

which looks like this:
[image]

when I hit tab key, the whole section (ordered list) lose focus and tab to next html element.

Could you show me how to write a code that can looks like what I need and accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a list of `<input type="text">` elements would do the trick. They can be edited, retain their values, and are, by default, tab activated:

```
    <div id="roster">
      <ol>
        <li><input type="text" value="Foo"></li>
        <li><input type="text" value="Bar"></li>
        <li><input type="text" value="Baz"></li>
        <li><input type="text" value="Qux"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

You can use CSS to disable the default borders of the inputs.